# Changing Variable Name After each Iteration in Loop

Tags: java

I have a problem I'm not sure how to solve. I need to change the name of the array being used in the loop to the next consecutive one. ie array xor1[] in first iteration then xor2[] in next and so on.

```
int xor1[] = {0,1,1,0,1,1};
int xor2[] = {0,1,1,1,0,1};

for(int ii = 0; ii < 2; ii++)
{
    int[] row = new int[2];

    //xor1 in next iteration should be xor2???
    row[0] = xor1[0];
    row[1] = xor1[5];
}
```

Note: there is far more than 2 iterations this is just for simplicity.

Comment: You can"t dynamiclly create variable, that's why we use arrays. How will you use `ii`, where will be stored value of xor2 you want ?

Comment: It seems like you need a 2D array. `int[][] xor = {{0,1,1,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,1,0,1}};`

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of the arrays, then iterate that.

```
int[] xor1 = {0,1,1,0,1,1};
int[] xor2 = {0,1,1,1,0,1};

int[][] xors = {xor1,xor2};
for (int[] xor : xors) {

    int[] row = new int[2];
    row[0] = xor[0];
    row[1] = xor[5];
}
```